# Python Elasticsearch DSL: how to sort by score in descending order?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a simple query:

```
Search().filter(
    "multi_match",
    fields=['name', 'description'],
    query='something',
    fuzziness="AUTO",
)
.sort("_score")
```

How can I change the order of sorting?

I tried:
`.sort("-_score")` it returns an error: `Sorting by '-_score' is not allowed.`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [ElasticSearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#_sort_order):

> The order defaults to `desc` when sorting on the `_score`, and defaults to `asc` when sorting on anything else.

So the default is fine (`.sort("_score")`), but if you want to order the worst matches first, then use `.sort({'_score': {'order': 'asc'}})`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch_dsl.Search.sort), have you tried to specify using a dictionary?

```py
Search().filter(
    "multi_match",
    fields=['name', 'description'],
    query='something',
    fuzziness="AUTO",
)
.sort({"_score": {"order": "desc"}})
```